# Procmon produces corrupt output file

Tags: sysinternals, procmon

I am trying to diagnose an issue causing my computer to crash when using audio for some time.

I tried running procmon (Process Monitor v 3.84) using the option of ring buffer to a file (to limit the amount of captured data to 4GB) and I used the computer with audio for some time until the machine crashed. After rebooting I was hoping that my procmon log file would have all the traces from just before the crash but this is what I got:

> "log.pml was not closed cleanly during capture and is corrupt".

It seems I cannot get back any of the logged information. Given that my computer runs fine and then everything freezes when the audio issue appears, is there a way I could generate a usable log file?

Comment: I would suggest you need a memory dump rather than a Process Monitor log.  You also say, "crash" and "freezes"? Which is it?  Typically either it crashes, which tends to mean a bugcheck (BSOD/GSOD) or it hangs indefinitely to the point where you need to power it off with the power button.  I assume it hangs indefinitely in which case, configure the machine to create a "Complete" or ideally "Active" dump. Then Google how to force a bugcheck using the keyboard. E.g. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard A dump is the best here

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335754/the-file-file-name-pml-was-not-closed-cleanly-during-capture-and-is-corrupt